# Jquery doesn't work with jquery-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I did bundle and generate install and now I have the jquery's files instead of prototype

I can see from mozilla firebug that the jquery's files are included, however I can't use jQuery or $ functions, the app/mozilla console don't know them.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

I'm using jquery-rails 1.0.12 and rails 3.0.8

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could give more details but here are some things you can try:

- Make sure that when you view the page source you can see the jQuery files are included. I usually have `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` between the HEAD tags
- You can test if everything is working by adding the following code:

  $(document).ready(function() {
           alert('hello world');
        });

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the line below is commented out (in application.rb) and that you have restarted your server.

## config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)